# key non identity on model creating

Tags: entity-framework, key

I do project in entity framework and i want my key to be **non** identity , i define it in the model building:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<trip>().HasKey(p =>  p.trip_id );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<trip>().Property(p => p.trip_id )
     .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```